# GWT three-tier architecture

Tags: gwt, jpa-2.0, three-tier

I am developing GWT based application using JPA as data access layer.  My application is required to support three-tier architecture. Main idea is to have **HTTP server (Apache)** with static content (html/javascript etc.), **Web Application server (Glassfish)** with business logic (servlets, beans, etc.) and **Database server (PostgreSQL)**.

Is there any easy way to divide content of war file generated for simple GWT application to achieve described architecture?

Maybe there is a maven plugin which will help in creating separate war files with static content and business logic.

I was also considering creating proxy which will intercept GWT-RPC calls and invoke business methods on remote server.

I found very interesting article describing such solution ([full article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84429/a-multitiered-java-application-with-gwt/)) but it requires a lot of work to achieve my goal. Hopefully there is a library or toolkit which will simplify proxy generation process.

**Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, just Tomcat instead of Glassfish, and maven to build everything. Here's how it works. Apache httpd and Tomcat are connected with mod_jk. Apache forwards all requests to Tomcat except for the GWT module dir (lets call it gwt_module), which contains all the GWT compiled stuff - that gets served by Apache and is configured to be cached. 
The rest - servlets basically, gets forwarded to Tomcat (RPC, RequestFactory, other servlets). MongoDB as a database server.

Here's the relevant httpd.conf section:

```
JkMount  /* webbalancer
JkUnMount /gwt_module/*  webbalancer
Alias /gwt_module "/srv/web/app_servers/tomcat-1/webapps/ROOT/gwt_module/"

<Directory  "/srv/web/app_servers/tomcat-1/webapps/ROOT/gwt_module/">
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes
    <FilesMatch "\.cache\.*">
        Header set Cache-control max-age=31536000
#       Header unset ETag
#       FileETag None
    </FilesMatch>

# turning off ETags, to force browsers to rely only on Cache-Control and Expires headers.
# for some reason, FF wasn't using the cache for JS files if ETags are on.
  Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
</Directory>

# Tell clients to keep images in the cache
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
#ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml A2592000

# Compress output for text
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript
```

Note: I'm not sure that serving static files with apache is faster than serving everything with only tomcat, I use apache for load balancing primarily.

Comment: This is quite a cool idea; I never considered fronting GlassFish with Apache HTTPD.  I will test mod_jk against my current GlassFish configuration, hopefully everything will go as smooth as you described. Thank you for your quick response and help.

Comment: I'm not sure that serving static files with apache is faster than serving everything with only tomcat, I use apache for load balancing primarily.